# How would I refactor the following code to use NSSet.objectsPassingTest()

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in my ViewController.  I'd like to refactor it to use `NSSet.objectsPassingTest()` so it's more concise and easier to follow.  I'm using Swift, so no Objective C.

```
let items = feed.items?.allObjects as! [Item]
var unreadCount = 0
for item in items {
    if !item.read {
        unreadCount = unreadCount + 1
    }
}
```

I've spent a few hours searching, but I have not been able to find an example that I can understand.

In case it's not clear, I'd like to replace `let items = feed.items?.allObjects as! [Item]` with `let items = feed.items?.objectsPassingTest()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach

```
let unreadCount = items.filter { !$0.read }.count
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `items` is an array rather than a set. Try this:

```
let unreadCount = items.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.read ? 0 : 1) }
```